# What is the easiest way to turn a mysql result variable into a multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

What is the easiest way to turn a mysql result variable into a multidimensional array in php?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you happen to be using the mysqli extension and php 5.3, you could use https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 8):

Run  [mysql_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)  in a loop.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $table[] = $row;
}

print_r($table);
```